# Ajax upload a file from browser to FTP server

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is it possible to uplaod a file from browser to FTP server using ajax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Browsers provide no APIs that allow writing to FTP from JavaScript.

You could [post the file to an HTTP end point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files) and then use server side code to push it to your FTP server.