# How to send file from AJAX to remote FTP directly?

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, ftp, xmlhttprequest

I would like to send file(s) with xhr from the user browser to remote FTP server without saving file to my server.

Is it possible? How can I do it? I am using PHP backend.

Comment: I would like to point out that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219984/ajax-upload-a-file-from-browser-to-ftp-server doesn't answer my question. I know I can't do it without any backend (directly from browser with JavaScript only), but I am asking if I can do it with PHP but without storing it on the server .

Comment: You did **not** ask if you could "do it with PHP but without storing it on the server". You literally asked "How to send file from AJAX to remote FTP **directly**?" Which is a duplicate question and was correctly answered previously.

Comment: Well, idbehold, I did mention PHP backend in my question. I didn't mention it in the title, but the title is not the entire question :) As You can see TecBrat has read my whole question and I got the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with an ajax upload script. I'm sure you can find one already written. Carefully read it and stop at the point where there is a temporary file on your server. (I know, technically this violates one of your specifications, but it's only temporary) Then use [ftp_put()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) to upload it. Then delete the temp file or just let it die on it's own.

Comment: Just a little disclaimer, I have never tried this, so if it proves false I'll gladly delete my answer.

Comment: I wonder how "temporary" this file will be. Is it like normal file that needs to be deleted (or is deleted after some time if I leave it) or is it something waiting in RAM for me to do somenthing with it? My problem is that I can't allow to store that file on the server because if I do, I need to meet high security requirements (which I won't).

Comment: According to [The Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), As soon as the script terminates. _The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed_

Comment: I think that makes me happy :) Thanks!

Comment: One thing to consider, in case it matters, is that the FTP server will see every upload as coming from your server, not the client.

Comment: Yeah, I know and That is acceptable. Thanks again!